# woocommerce product-image thumbnail wrong src in shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, src

I'm building a WP e-commerce website using MAMP. I'm working with woocommerce 3.3.4 and the issue is in the "card-image", where the rsc="" appear like this:
"8888/wordpress/" rather than "http://localhost:8888/wordpress".
I hope you can help me figuring out the problem. has been many hours that I'm trying to figure it out the issue but I can't came up with anything.

Comment: In General Setting how did you set the site addresses?

Comment: Hi, in General setting the site address is this: http://localhost:8888/wordpress

Comment: I mean is: localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/img.jpg with the "http://". I don't know if it can help but I'm using the last version of hestia template. it's like if the root path is cut

Comment: and do you have any idea what function is being used to populate the image src in this particular section?

Comment: I can see that the hooking problem is "<?php echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail ); ?>"
in 
wp-content/themes/hestia/inc/woocommerce/functions.php 
<div class="card-image">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( ) ); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
     <?php echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail ); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="ripple-container"></div>
   </div>

Comment: function hestia_woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
 $thumbnail = function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail' ) ? woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail() : '';
 if ( empty( $thumbnail ) && function_exists( 'wc_placeholder_img' ) ) {
  $thumbnail = wc_placeholder_img();
 }
 if ( ! empty( $thumbnail ) ) {
  ?>
   <div class="card-image">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( ) ); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
     <?php echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail ); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="ripple-container"></div>
   </div>
  <?php
 }
}

Comment: Could it be the `woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()` that is causing the issue? Have you tried to comment it out? Did you debug the code to see which if statement is being met? Can you check what `get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID() );` returns?

Comment: this is what i did :

<div class="card-image">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( ) ); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
     <?php echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail ); ?>
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID() ); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="ripple-container"></div>
   </div>

and i can see the right path of the thumbnail but (of course) no images

Comment: but if i go with the inspect element i can still see the broken path

Comment: If you try this: what happens? <div class="card-image"> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( ) ); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"> <?php echo <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID() ); ?>" /> </a> <div class="ripple-container"></div> </div>

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED. I was working with MAMP and HESTIA. In MAMP I had the port set as 8888 and 8889 but evidently the last update of HESTIA template doesn’t allow other port from the default one. I set as `APACHE: 80 (NGINX:80) MYSQL:3306` and now it’s working correctly! :) thank you so much @OmarTanti for your help!

Comment: Glad you solved the issue. I would suggest to put your solution as an answer in case other have some issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "echo wp_kses_post( $thumbnail );" I have used "echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();"  so the images are visible now